# Why download not working in Galaxy Tab 2 gt-p5113? while ok in all device

Tags: android, download

The Device Like

1. Samsung GalaxyTAB2 GT-P5113 Android OS 4.1.1
2. Lenovo Android Mobile

In many device my InternetReachability code will work

But  above device  has not work

```
       Toste Message  "Not Connect to the Internet"
```

InternetReachability code

```
public boolean currentStatus(Context context)
    {

        try
        {
            if (context==null)
                return false;

            ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            return ( connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting() || connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting() );

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And when i can download product from Amazon with out internet InternetReachability code

The error will occur  like this

```
05-01 13:26:36.154: I/System.out(16813): THREAD IS ALIVE.
05-01 13:26:36.404: E/SpannableStringBuilder(16813): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-01 13:26:36.404: E/SpannableStringBuilder(16813): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-01 13:05:13.589: I/System.out(15658): THREAD IS ALIVE.
05-01 13:05:15.425: I/System.out(15658): ERROR in run() ----> : Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 6D55BDA68E575EC9, AWS Error Code: RequestTimeTooSkewed, AWS Error Message: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large., S3 Extended Request ID: 8mfkdgLLXu2Zt1dsAkBdwAw7Qd2Ha4Ngyazg807u504/ZGbnS1tWNilV8kVUaknW
05-01 13:05:15.425: W/System.err(15658): Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 6D55BDA68E575EC9, AWS Error Code: RequestTimeTooSkewed, AWS Error Message: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large., S3 Extended Request ID: 8mfkdgLLXu2Zt1dsAkBdwAw7Qd2Ha4Ngyazg807u504/ZGbnS1tWNilV8kVUaknW
05-01 13:05:15.433: W/System.err(15658):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:583)
05-01 13:05:15.433: W/System.err(15658):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:317)
05-01 13:05:15.433: W/System.err(15658):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:167)
05-01 13:05:15.433: W/System.err(15658):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2781)
05-01 13:05:15.433: W/System.err(15658):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:872)
05-01 13:05:15.433: W/System.err(15658):    at org.Infoware.fb.DownloadThread.run(DownloadThread.java:113)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658): Unable to execute HTTP request: No peer certificate
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:137)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:285)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:167)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2781)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:872)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/AmazonHttpClient(15658):  at org.Infoware.fb.DownloadThread.run(DownloadThread.java:113)
05-01 13:05:19.199: I/System.out(15658): ERROR in run() ----> : com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: No peer certificate
05-01 13:05:19.199: W/System.err(15658): com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: No peer certificate
05-01 13:05:19.199: W/System.err(15658):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:332)
05-01 13:05:19.199: W/System.err(15658):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:167)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2781)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:872)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.Infoware.fb.DownloadThread.run(DownloadThread.java:113)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:137)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:285)
05-01 13:05:19.207: W/System.err(15658):    ... 4 more
```

So what i have to do.... 
my InternetReachability code and downloading code work properly in all device
But the above device has not work properly... 
So please help me

Comment: @Alpan-reboot your device and then try to run.I am not sure but try it.

Comment: @Pratik I do this but cant success.....

Comment: @Pratik is this any possibility of device setting Or One another thing the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 GT-p5100 have the SIM card functionality and Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 GT-p5113 have no functionality of SIM card

Comment: @Pratik my app download more than 10000 above in just 4 month the app link is "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.Infoware.ChildBible#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwib3JnLkluZm93YXJlLkNoaWxkQmlibGUiXQ.." if you want to see download or not follow the above link

Comment: @Pratik yes bro... But i am in big trouble if you have any idea about this issue.... any type of answer will strongly acceptable...

Answer (score 1):

The error code says that the clock on your device is skewed. Did you check that the system clock is correct?

Comment: Yes, this was a silly question.. and i solve the issue about but still i have the issue abut InternetReachability problem..